# Make bopomofo symbol (zhuyin fuhao) "ㄧ" (U+3127) vertical in horizontal text

Tags: cjk, xecjk

The symbol "ㄧ" (U+3127) should be a vertical line in horizontal text, and a horizontal line in vertical text. However, there's only one unicode. It's supposed to be displayed according to the text type automatically. (And it's a vertical line in my web browser now)  [Wikipedia introduction (Chinese)](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%84%A7#%E5%AD%97%E5%BD%A2)

In horizontal text:
[image: horizontal text],
and in vertical text:
[image: vertical text]

When I use the symbol in horizontal text, it's always a horizontal line:

[image: text]

What is the correct way to make it conform the rule?

My code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[slantfont, boldfont]{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{Source Han Serif CN}
\setCJKmonofont{Source Han Mono EL}
\setCJKsansfont{Source Han Sans CN}
\XeTeXlinebreaklocale "zh"
\XeTeXlinebreakskip = 0pt plus 1pt
\begin{document}
  bopomofo: ㄐㄧㄝ
\end{document}
```